# Can I make a contextMenuStrip for columns only not headers in a dataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenu

I have a contextMenuStrip attached to a dataGridView and when I right-click any where on the daaGridView including the header and the blank area that doesn't have any data rows the contextMenuStrip appears.

I want the contextMenuStrip to appear when I right-click on the data rows ONLY. How can I do this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use HitTest method of datagridview in order to find out if any datarow is clicked or not. Within Mousedown event of the grid, use the following code:

```
var info = dataGrid1.HitTest(e.X,e.Y);
if(info.RowIndex!=-1)// datarow is clicked.
    contextMenu.Show(dataGrid1, e.Location);
```

info.RowIndex will be -1 for columnheaders or background area. Also don't preset dataGrid1.ContextMenu property at design time (leave it unassigned). So that your dataGrid1 can not show contextMenu by default on right click.

Comment: @Bob if you think my answer does not solve your problem let me know but if it does then please mark it as accepted.