# How to disable a context menu when clicking on DataGridView header

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenu

I've created a context menu and named it GridMenu, I then set the ContextMenuStrip property of a DataGridView to GridMenu. I only want the context menu to show when right-clicking on the data rows of that DataGridView. Not its column headers.

So how do I disable the context menu if any of the column headers are right-clicked?

Comment: Have you looked at adding some code to the [ColumnHeaderMouseClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadermouseclick?view=net-5.0) event? Please show what you've tried so we can see what's not working.

Comment: All I've tried is just what I've said in the question. I'm still trying to figure this one out.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970287/can-i-make-a-contextmenustrip-for-columns-only-not-headers-in-a-datagridview

Answer (score 0):

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
        if (DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index < 0)
            e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your Form load event:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow gridViewRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            gridViewRow.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
        }
```